# How do I format the output of cut to the following format?

Tags: text-formatting, cut

last part of the command:

```
| cut -d' ' -f3
```

output:

```
4
10
```

required format:

```
4,10
```

I'm guessing `echo` (and `sort`?) is to be used in some way, but I can't quite place my finger on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the following code:

```
| cut -d' ' -f3 | paste -sd ','
```